# How to deploy/push to openshift 3?

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-3

I am trying to migrate my openshift-2 experiment to openshift-3 free.

I am actually stuck with a very simple question?
**How do I push/deploy my sourcecode? I cannot find the openshift-3 git path in the UI**

In openshift-2 it looked like this 
ssh://67823a0c1e66c209762e7@app-loremipsum.rhcloud.com/~/git/someapp.git/

Thanks

Comment: Consider starting out by reading the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html and work through exercises at https://learn.openshift.com That will give you a better understanding of how OpenShift 3 works. You can also find various blog posts at https://blog.openshift.com

Comment: What type of project are you gonna to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer. Take a look at the python app. The [project itself is hosted on github](https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/blob/master/2.7/README.md). It uses [S2I](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) to build a docker pod from [the software collections project for a python version, e.g. 2.7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/). The resulting docker image is then deployed to openshift.

If you do the same, your application will be deployed. Though this may not be the main approach for openshift.

I asked about [deploying kaa to openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568713/how-to-get-kaa-deployed-on-openshift), and am thinking of the approach above. Hopefully someone can figure out a clear path.