# how to get kaa deployed on openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, kaa, openshift-3

The [Kaa platform](https://www.kaaproject.org/overview/) as an [IoT cloud platform](https://www.postscapes.com/internet-of-things-platforms/) is prebuilt to run on amazon aws or a virtualbox sandbox. Is it immediately deployable to [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html), especially the starter free plan? If not, what it takes to get it to work?

I have looked at the [python on openshift](https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/blob/master/2.7/README.md) which uses the [S2I](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) to dockerize a [software collections version of python, e.g. 2.7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/). I'm wondering how these projects or technologies would work together to make Kaa to run on multiple platforms, or to make more versions/flavors/variants of Kaa to run on platforms. An interesting question, but I'm not sure the way of thinking is right. Though this is just to add some hints of the background information that I've been looking at, may or may not be related to the questions asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different workflows to achieve the goal:

It seems there are Docker images ready to use[1], so you can try deploy it in Openshift and see what happens.

You can create a custom s2i[2] image in Openshift and create a Dockerfile with all the base software you need to run Kaa.

You can create a Dockerfile (maybe editing the exsisting Kaa Dockerfile) that contains/add all the software you need, then create a BuildConfig with docker strategy[3] and run it in an Openshift project to add your Kaa image to the imagestream and then deploy Pods from your Kaa imagestream with a Deploymentconfig[4].

[1]: https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Docker-deployment/

[2]: https://blog.openshift.com/create-s2i-builder-image/

[3]: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#docker-strategy-options

[4]: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration